# How can i display elements from one table to another using a button?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of aliments and i want to make an "Add to Meal Planner" button that can take a certain aliment from my table(Aliments) and put it in another table(Meal Planner).

```
  public ActionResult MealPlannerAliments(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        MealPlanner mealPlannerAliment = db.MealPlanners.Find(id);
        if (mealPlannerAliment == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(mealPlannerAliment);
    }
```

I used this code(in controller) to store the Id that the user clicked on...but i don't know how to continue

Comment: You have to find the row in the other table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You create and use HttpSession variable to store those selected elements and then display into another table whenever required.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use MealPlanner object mealPlannerAliment in the view and diplay it 
on button event in another with the help the object data

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how the Aliment and MealPlanner classes are modeled, but that gives you an idea how to do it.

first you check if the Aliment with the Id parameter is valid, if so, you check in MealPlanners if it already contains the Aliment, if not, you populate the MealPlanner object and call the Add() and SaveChanges() methods;

```
public ActionResult MealPlannerAliments(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Aliment aliment = new Aliment();
    aliment = db.Aliment.Find(id);

     if (aliment == null)
     {
        return HttpNotFound();
     }
     else
     {
        MealPlanner mealPlannerAliment = db.MealPlanners.Find(aliment.id);
        if (mealPlannerAliment == null)
        {
            mealPlannerAliment = aliment;
            try{
                db.Add(mealPlannerAliment);
                db.saveChanges();
            }
            catch{
                ViewBag.Error('Error! Try Later!')
            }
        }
        else{
            ViewBag.Error('this Aliment already exists in the Meal Planner')
        }
     }


    return View();
}
```